# Importing an excel .csv file and adding it to a column in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, phpmyadmin

I've read through some other posts and nothing quite answers my question specifically.

I have an existing database in phpMyAdmin - a set of pin codes we use to collect contest entries.

The DB has about 10,000 pin codes in it.

I need to add 250 "New" codes to it. I have an excel file that is stripped down to a single column .csv, no header - just codes.

What I need to do is import this into the table named "pin2" and add these to the row called "pin"

The other rows are where entrants would add names and phone numbers, so are all "null"

I've uploaded a screen grab of the structure.

[DB Structure http://www.redpointdesign.ca/sql.png](http://www.redpointdesign.ca/sql.png)

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wants to do using csv
Then you need to need to follow these steps

1. Manually define autoincremented value in first comlumn.
2. In other column you have to externally define it as a NULL,

otherwise you will get **Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.**

because column with no value is not consider by phpmyadmin[image]

Them click on import in phpmyadmin and you are done ..

Comment: Basically exporting the structure out as a csv, then copy the new pin codes into it...then import back into phpMyAdmin... sounds logical.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `LOAD DATA` query similar to this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'pincodes.csv'
INTO TABLE pin2 (pin)
```

If the pin codes in the csv file are enclosed in quotes you may also need to include an `ENCLOSED BY` clause.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'pincodes.csv'
INTO TABLE pin2
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'
(pin)
```